# Too many query rows: 50001 in export csv

Tags: query, limits

I need to create a axpex class that create and send a csv report.

In a @future static method I have this query:

```
List<Activity__c> activityList = [
SELECT fields....
, (SELECT Id, fields... FROM ContactAttendances__r WHERE ...)
, (SELECT Id, fields... FROM UserAttendances__r WHERE ...)
FROM Activity__c WHERE Active__c = true AND ...];
```

...More process with this activityList and call another private methods...
Finally I create blob and send it via email.

The query returns 9000 rows without subquery.
With subquery throws a limit exception (Too many query rows: 50001)
I see apex batch but it does not work for data return, only for insert/updates/etc.

Any idea to avoid this error?

Comment: What data are you trying to include in your outgoing email? You may need to use a batch process to accumulate summary information. Even in a batch, you cannot query or store an arbitrarily large amount of data - the governor limits still apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue here is that you are using a `future` method and that the limit of records returned with a SOQL query in `future` method is same as synchronous limit, i.e., of 50,000. If you refer to the [Execution Governors and Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm), and refer "Per-Transaction Apex Limits" section, you will find this detail in there as below, which does not differentiate this particular limit but instead is applicable to both sync and async transactions.

> This table lists limits for synchronous Apex and asynchronous Apex (Batch Apex and **future** methods) when they’re different. **Otherwise, this table lists only one limit that applies to both synchronous and asynchronous Apex**.
>
> Total number of records retrieved by SOQL queries -- 50,000

So irrespective of a synchronous or asynchronous transaction, the number of records returned is maximum 50,000 and that is where your method is failing.

---

As for your question:

> Any idea to avoid this error?

What you need here is to use an [Apex Batch](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm) instead of a future method. And because future or batch will be both executed asynchronously, so you may just like to promote your code in a batch class.

In the same link for governor limits, you will notice this statement as below:

> These limits count for each Apex transaction. **For Batch Apex**, these limits are reset for each execution of a batch of records in the execute method.

This signifies that every batch which is capable of handling a maximum of 50 million records returned by `Database.QueryLocator` (anything more than that still fails) but in batches sent to the `execute` method.

Best practices around [future](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_invoking_future_methods.htm) method also mentions to use a batch for performance reasons.

> Consider using batch Apex instead of future methods to process large numbers of records.

Comment: It work if I do not call another method and I use QueryLocator. Thanks!